# Create new VSCode C++ project folder: via Developer Command Prompt or GUI?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, ide

I'm new to VSCode and had a question about creating your project folder. [This vscode site resource](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc#_create-hello-world) teaches you to create the project via DevCMD. I can't tell what the difference is with creating the folder in your OS (Windows) and then opening the folder as a project via the VSC GUI, but the latter doesn't work. Can you tell me why?

P.S., I'm relearning C++ and would like to find a place, chatroom, forum, where I can ask stupid questiolns until I've learned the fundamentals again. If you have any recommendations I'd appreciate a message.

Answer (score 0):

MS C++ compiler needs specific environment variables set.

There is a batch file (search with `Visual Studio Tools` in Windows) that creates a CMD.exe terminal and sets the variables. That is DevCMD. It is called `Developer Command Prompt for VSxxxx`

You need to start VSC from this terminal so the internal terminal also has these variables